# How do I generate all $n\times m$ matrices s.t. $a_{i,j} \in {a ... b}$?

Tags: matrix

Is there a fast and clean way of generating all possible $n\times m$ matrices s.t. $a_{i,j} \in \{a ... b\}$ - much like Range does in $N$?

Consider for example that for $n,m = 2$, $a=0$, $b=2$ I would like to have

```
{{{0,0},{0,0}},
 {{0,0},{0,1}},
 {{0,0},{0,2}},
 {{0,0},{1,0}},
 ...
 {{2,2},{2,2}}}
```

For the $2 \times 2$ case I got it working in the following horribly dirty way:

```
GenMat[a, b] :=
  Partition[
   Partition[
    Flatten[
     Table[{{x, y}, {w, z}},
      {x, a, b}, {y, a, b}, {w, a, b}, {z, a, b}
      ]
     ],
    2],
   2];
```

I am however not pleased with it, not to say ashamed.

How would I best improve upon it and generalize it?

Thanks.

Comment: `Partition[#, 2] & /@ Tuples[Range[0, 2], 4]`

Comment: `f[a_, b_, n_] := Partition[#, n] & /@ Tuples[Range[a, b], n^2]`

Comment: Sweet. 
So concise.
Is by the way this exactly the same as Map[Partition[#1, n] &, Tuples[Range[a, b], n^2]]?

Answer (score 6):

```
matF = Tuples[#1, {##2}] &;;
```

**Examples:**

```
matF[Range[0, 2], 2, 2] // Short
```

> {{{0,0},{0,0}},{{0,0},{0,1}},<<77>>,{{2,2},{2,1}},{{2,2},{2,2}}}

```
MatrixForm /@ matF[Range[0, 2], 2, 2]
```

> [image]

```
matF[Range[3, 5], 2, 3] // Short
```

> {{{3,3,3},{3,3,3}},{{3,3,3},{3,3,4}},<<726>>,{{5,5,5},{5,5,5}}}

Alternatively, you can use

```
matF2 = Tuples[Range[#, #2], {#3, #4}] &;
```

`matF2[a, b, c, d]` gives the same output as `matF[Range[a, b], c, d]`.